# I have a problem with this code. some idea?

Tags: matlab

I have the next code: BD_MACRO, but when rum, I obtain this answer in command window in matlab

> > BD_MACROPA
> >     Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
> >     logicals.

Error in BD_MACROPA (line 27)
        dH = betaH((aH - bH) * H(i-1) + phi * h(i-1)) -
        alphaH * Z(i-1);

```
[![% MODELO BASICO

dt=0.01; % pasos en el tiempo
tiempo=2000; % anos de evolucion
%CONDICIONES INICIALES
H(1)=100; h(1)=250; Z(1)=200; t(1)=0; 
%PARAMETROS
%ADULTOS Y PREADULTOS
aH = 147.9; 
ah = 34.25;
bh = 0.20;
bH = 0.20;
phi= 0.25;
ro = 34.24;
muZ = 0.15;
H0 = 10.0;
alphaH = 0.000001;
alphah = 0.000001;
lambda = 6.0;
betaH = 0.095;
betah = 0.095;
rand('state',sum(100*clock)); % semilla de generador de numeros aleatorios,
%
numreps=5000; % numero de realizaciones
for j=1:numreps
    for i=2:tiempo
        dH = betaH((aH - bH) * H(i-1) + phi * h(i-1)) - alphaH * Z(i-1);
        dh = betah((ah - bh) * h(i-1) + ro * H(i-1)) - alphah * Z(i-1);
        dZ = Z(i-1) * (lambda * H(i-1)./(H0 + H(i-1)) + (r - mu + (bH + bh)) - alpha * (H(i-1) + Z(i-1))./H(i-1));
        H(i) = H(i-1) + dt * dH;
        h(i) = h(i-1) + dt * dh;
        Z(i) = Z(i-1) + dt * dZ;
        t(i) = t(i-1) + dt;
    end
end
% Create figure
figure1 = figure;

% Create axes
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1);
hold(axes1,'on');

% Create multiple lines using matrix input to plot
plot1 = plot(t,H,t,P,t,Z,'LineWidth',2);
set(plot1(1),'DisplayName','H');
set(plot1(2),'DisplayName','P','LineStyle','--');
set(plot1(3),'DisplayName','Z','LineStyle','.-');
%plot(t,H,t,P)
% Create xlabel
xlabel('Tiempo');

% Create ylabel
ylabel('Tamaño de la Población');

box(axes1,'on');
grid(axes1,'on');
% Set the remaining axes properties
set(axes1,'FontSize',12);
% Create legend
legend1 = legend(axes1,'show');
set(legend1,'FontSize',20);
legend('Hospederos Adultos', 'Hospederos Preadultos','Zoosporas');][1]][1]
```

Comment: Hi - this is not a suitable title for a question! If someone is searching for similar help, this title will be useless. Please see here for tips: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing a * sign in the statement

```
dH = betaH((aH - bH) * H(i-1) + phi * h(i-1)) - alphaH * Z(i-1);
```

Right now, this is trying to access 14833-th element of dH whereas you define dH as a scalar. I think what you want is

```
dH = betaH*((aH - bH) * H(i-1) + phi * h(i-1)) - alphaH * Z(i-1);
```

Same issue with dH. You also have undeclared variables alpha, mu and r in the statement

```
dZ = Z(i-1) * (lambda * H(i-1)./(H0 + H(i-1)) + (r - mu + (bH + bh)) - alpha * (H(i-1) + Z(i-1))./H(i-1));
```

Comment: Thanks!  Last night I was very tired, I can't see this error, I am, apologize for this dud